# Where is the networker public key?

Tags: backup, rpm, gpg

I am trying to install a networker backup client on linux (CentOS).

At the moment I have to use "yum install --nogpgcheck" to do this, since I could not find the public gpg-key for their rpms.

According to [the installation manual](https://www.emc.com/collateral/TechnicalDocument/docu81532.pdf) this is the way to do it.

But this will disable the consistency checks designed to keep my system safe and ensures that only original rpms are installed.

Has anyone out there has found the public key?

Comment: Are the RPMs really signed? `rpm -qip <rpm> | grep Signature` Perhaps you can look up the key via its ID.

Comment: @fuero Yes, it is and the signature can not be found in public GPG databases.